# How to return a simple boolean value as plain text with @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I just want to return the text "true" via a simple servlet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Boolean isValid() {
    return true;
}
```

Result: `406 - The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.`.

Why? How can I just return that simple value?
There is no difference if I change the return type to `String "true"`.

Comment: What do you want the response to be? A string of `true`?

Comment: Exactly. I just want to return "true".

Comment: Seems like there were accept headers in the request. Can you find out what they are/were? Maybe you'll have to provide a mime type for the response ( like text/plain or application/xml ... )

Comment: I think you are looking for [String#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28boolean%29). You would write it like `return String.valueOf(true);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Spring MVC default converters can't convert `Boolean` to `text/plain`. Only when I tried a request with `Accept: application/json` it worked.

I'd suggest changing the return type to `String` since it's what you want to return anyway.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String isValid() {
    return Boolean.TRUE.toString();
}
```

This way, requests without the `Accept` header will work fine, but you can also add `Accept: text/plain` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String isValid() {
   return "true";
}
```

And remove/set proper header value to the `accept` header for your request.

read more about http status codes [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)